# User CPU time of specific child process after first output to stdout

Tags: c, unix, time, process, fork

I'm working on a program which may spawn multiple child processes, and I need to get precise information about the CPU time used by each child process, even if there are several child processes running simultaneously. I'm doing this using wait4(2) on a separate thread of the parent process, which works quite well.

However, this approach provides the *total* time spent by a specific child process, and I'm only interested in the amount of time spent after a particular event, namely the child process' first output to stdout. I've looked into other ways of getting the CPU time of child processes, such as getrusage(2) and times(3), but these don't seem to be able to distinguish between multiple child processes' times, and instead provide the sum of all child processes' times.

I'm working on a text editor application that lets users run scripts and code in a variety of different languages, and the app has a built-in code timing feature. The app relies on bash scripts to run the users code, and the first thing my bash scripts do are to output a start-of-heading byte (0x02). After this the bash script does whatever it needs to do to run the users code, and that is the thing I want to time. Bash may do a bit of initialization (to set up PATH variables etc) which may take 30 or 40 ms to complete, and I don't want that initialization to be timed along with the rest. If the users code is for instance a simple Hello World type program in C, the timing feature might display something like 41 ms instead of the actual 1 ms which it took to run their code.

Any ideas on how this might be done?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

A couple of possible solutions come to mind.  They don't get CPU time after first output exactly, but they may avoid the problem you're dealing with.

The first is to get rid of the bash scripts and just do the equivalent work in your program before running the user's code (between `fork()` and `exec()`, for example).  That way the child process' CPU time from `wait4()` doesn't include your extra setup.

Another possibility is to write a simple application that does nothing but run the user's application and report its CPU time back to your main application.  That runner application can then be called from your scripts to run the user's program, rather than calling the user's program directly.  The runner application might itself use `fork()`/`exec()`/`wait4()` to run the user's program, and could report the information from `wait4()` to your main program through any of a variety of means such as a named pipe, message queue, socket, or even just writing the information to a file your main program can open afterward.  That way your bash scripts can do work both before and after running the user's program that won't be included in the CPU time reported by the runner application.  You'd probaby want the runner to accept an argument like the name of a pipe or an output file in addition to the user's program's path and arguments so that you can control how the information is reported -- that way you could run more than one instance of the runner application and still keep the information they report separate.

---

If you *do* want to include the work done by the script, but not the time taken to load `bash`, then you could signal the main program by echoing something to a pipe from the bash script before and after the parts you want to time.  The main program can then measure the time between the start and stop signals, which will at least get you wall-clock time (though not actual CPU time).  Otherwise I'm not sure there's a way to perfectly measure the CPU time for just part of the script without using a modified bash (which I'd avoid if possible).

Comment: Thanks for such a good answer. I was hoping there was a simple way to  do what I need that I'd missed, but I guess there isn't.. Your idea of creating a simple application to do the timing work sounds like it might work, I'll give it a try and see how it goes.